# How do I make a critical section with Boost?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, critical-section

For my cross-platform application I have started to use Boost, but I can't understand how I can implement code to reproduce behavior of Win32's critical section or .Net's `lock`.

I want to write a method `Foo` that can be called from different threads to control write operations to shared fields. Recursive calls within the same thread should be allowed (Foo() -> Foo()).

In C# this implementation is very simple:

```
object _synch = new object();
void Foo()
{
    lock (_synch)  // one thread can't be lock by him self, but another threads must wait untill
    {
        // do some works
        if (...) 
        {
           Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With boost you can use boost::lock_guard<> class:

```
class test
{
public:
 void testMethod()
 {
  // this section is not locked
  {
   boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(m_guard);
   // this section is locked
  }
  // this section is not locked
 }
private:
    boost::recursive_mutex m_guard;
};
```

PS These classes located in [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/index.html) library.

Comment: Your recommendation is very useful. I have fixed my error, BUT i have performance suppression! more then 3 times! =( (before that fix i used  unique_lock<shared_mutex>)

Comment: Can you provide code samples where you using shared resources? Also check this http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/mutexes/locking.html#Shared. Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Try to avoid using recursive locking, may be by moving guard to outer scope. Recursive mutexes can be slower then simple ones.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rewrite of your example, using Boost.Thread: I removed the comments, but otherwise, it should be a 1-to-1 rewrite.

```
boost::recursive_mutex mtx;

void Foo()
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (...) 
    {
       Foo();
    }
}
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html).

Note that Boost defines a number of different mutex types. Because your example shows the lock being taken recursively, we need to use at least `boost::recursive_mutex`.

There are also different types of locks. In particular, if you want a reader-writer lock (so that multiple readers can hold the lock simultaneously, as long as no writer has the lock), you can use `boost::shared_lock` instead of `lock_guard`.